# An equivalent condition of being $d$-Leray ($d$th and above homology groups vanish)

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Given a simplicial complex $X$ on vertex set $V$, $X$ is called $d$-Leray if the reduced homology group satisfying $\tilde{H}_i(Y)=0$ for all induced subcomplexes $Y\subseteq X$ (i.e., Y=X[S] for some $S\subseteq V$) and for all $i\ge d$.

One claims that "Equivalently $X$ is $d$-Leray if $\tilde{H}_i(lk(X,\sigma))=0$ for all $\sigma\in X$ and $i\ge d$", where $$lk(X,\sigma):=\{\tau\in X: \tau\cap\sigma=\emptyset, \tau\cup\sigma\in X\}$$
is the link of a simplex $\sigma \in X$. (See, e.g., page 3 of [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870804000969))

I am wondering why they are equivalent?

I am trying to see if $lk(X,\sigma)$ runs over all induced subcomplex of $X$, but it is not clear to me, since I think $lk(X,\sigma)\neq X[V-\sigma]$. ($X[V-\sigma]$ may include some simplex whose union with $\sigma$ is not in $X$?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a proof in Proposition 3.1 of [1] by the same authors. They say it's "well-known".

[1] *Kalai, Gil; Meshulam, Roy*, [**Intersections of Leray complexes and regularity of monomial ideals**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2006.01.005), J. Comb. Theory, Ser. A 113, No. 7, 1586-1592 (2006). [ZBL1105.13026](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1105.13026).

Comment: As a supplement of (6) in their proof, the third term in the M-V should be $\tilde{H}_i(Z_1) \oplus\tilde{H}_i(Z_2)$. Since $Z_2$ is a star, it vanishes. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4491366/the-reduced-homology-group-of-a-star-of-a-vertex-vanishes?noredirect=1#comment9421816_4491366